# No Spaces in the organisation

Tags: ibm-cloud

I currently have 2 spaces in my Bluemix account , (Dev & demo) . I want to create a Node-RED application using Bluemix .

When I click on Create App button , but it gives the following error message.

BXNUI0514E: The 'qawithwatson' organization has no spaces for which you are a developer. Try to select another organization or create a space.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a vendor support question related to a specific account. It should be addressed directly to the vendor's support staff. It is not a general programming question that is of use to others.

Answer (score 3):

Can you verify that you have selected the correct Bluemix organization (account icon in the top right, below the region selector is the organization selector), it seems that you've selected an organization which you are member but do not have the space developer role (see roles description at  https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/admin/index.html#userroles).